# IIS Bad Request - Invalid Hostname

Tags: asp.net, iis-10

Until windows updates I was able call API using IP address of server from outside of server. After updating windows of API server, I am getting **HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid.**.

Now when I call API using ServerName it works, but not not works using IP address.

**What I Tested**:

1. Added new inbound rule in widonws firewall - not helped
2. Added IP in site binding and got **timeout** error.
3. Using **Servername** Postman is **able** call API
4. Using **IP** , Postman is **not able** call API

How I can find the issue?

[image]

Comment: Can you make it part of the question what are the site bindings you set on the Micro service machine? https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html#background And also what's the code in your API gateway that makes the backend calls?

Comment: Same on using Postman

Comment: Again, show more details and don't ask others to guess.

Comment: @LexLi attached site bindings, let me know if you need more details

Comment: There's no information in the question except the default configuration of site bindings. The talk about microservices and gateways explains nothing nor does it contain any information - microservices are just services and `gateways` is whatever people are trying to sell you. `Api Gateway is able call microservices using servername, but not able call using IP address` that just means you're using the wrong IP. Or that you're trying to use an internal IP from another network, or the public internet

Comment: please let me know what info you need?  it worked using internal IP , but now not works, the IP is correct, ping to server name resolves this IP

Comment: What do you mean by "API Gateway" anyway? What software are you using and what is it doing? Server names are resolved into IPs using DNS, not API Gateways. There's no way for the web server to know which domain name you used from the TCP connection itself. That's why HTTP requests include a [HOST Header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Host) that contains the domain name you used. You can create multiple DNS records that point to the same IP but you also have to configure the web server to route different HOST headers to different virtual sites, through Site Bindings

Comment: @KamilIbadov `what info you need` you didn't provide any info, that's the problem.

Comment: API gateway is an asp.net api, same occurs when I try to call microservice (asp.net web api ) using Postman from the server where Apigateway is stored.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the question is why it not works directly using IP?

Comment: At least the site binding you showed rules out the typical 400 causes, but you didn't show any code yet to rule out other common causes. Besides, there can be things in between if you draw out a detailed network topology. So, you have to move further on your own, as no one here has access to that environment. Just don't assume "Until windows updates" at this very moment, as if that's the case the internet will be flooded with similar reports (but clearly not yet).

Comment: @LexLi Is there way debug it? I see  

when I stop IIS I am getting error quickly
when I adding IP to site binding it goes to timeout


which probably means issue is related with IIS

Comment: could you try adding the site binding as shown in this image and try to access it[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSlQB.png)

Comment: tried, same problem

Comment: could you please share the host file entry with us? try to set AllowedHosts to configure Allowed Origins in your code. set the inbound rules that allow access via the specific port (9121 in this case) using the IP address in your firewall. Try flushing the DNS cache or test the IP address access in a different network environment. check the network adapter settings to ensure that the network adapter is bound to the correct IP address.